# debugkit Fatal error: Class 'App'

Tags: cakephp

Hi everyone please help me

I use debug kit to debug my application

but it gave me the error like this

Fatal error: Class 'App' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\a\app\plugins\debug_kit\controllers\components\toolbar.php

any suggestion please?

Comment: Can you show some code where you're trying to use the plugin?  The fact that the `App` class wasn't included likely means you have some other problem as this is a core Cake utility.

Comment: I did exactly what the document of debugkit. First unzip the package to app/plugins. Second, in app_controller var components = array('DebugKit.Toolbar');

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may be using incompatible versions? Click the "Switch branches" menu on [GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) and check you are using the correct version for your CakePHP installation.

> DebugKit has several versions, they are compatible with different
>   release of CakePHP.
>
> - 1.0 -> 1.2 are compatible with CakePHP 1.2.x. These releases of
>     DebugKit will not work with CakePHP 1.3.
> - 1.3 is compatible with CakePHP 1.3.x only. It will not work with
>     CakePHP 1.2.

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but it does not change anything.thank you